# Java crash during garbage collection

Tags: java, crash, garbage-collection

I have the following problem: Java application without using JNI regularly crashes during garbage collection:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=3032, tid=0x0000000000000500

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_211-b12) (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.211-b12 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  0x0000000000000000
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
Current thread (0x000000000323f000):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000017af0000,0x0000000017bf0000] [id=1280]
```

I don't override the finalize method.

What could cause such crashes?
If gc crash during validation of pointers to objects, probably, we can see what gc collecting before the crash?

I have tried many versions of jdk8, the error is the same everywhere.

Comment: Are you running it on Windows? It could be something related to UAC, for example https://java.com/en/download/help/exception_access.xml.

Comment: On Linux run also, there is a crash the same, but with SIGSEGV

Comment: Is the stack trace you provided above complete? There is some detail in the Java troubleshooting guide that might be helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/crashes001.html#CIHJABGA

Comment: In this guide there is no problem with GCTaskThread. Completed crash: [link](https://pastebin.com/raw/fjqc5v2w)

Comment: It's too hard to say the certain solution but Have you forgotten to add **close()** (resource, netty channel, resource) method?

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you are running out of memory.

Comment: Java shouldn't crash when memory runs out, it should clean it, shouldn't it?